# position of image in Css

Tags: javascript, css, image

When i show the image its going to the left most position of the div.

i know its not a good question but i unable to solve this so posted.

Actually i am dynamically adding html tags. I am adding a having 2 anchor and 3 images in which 2 are visible and one is in visible. when you click on any one of that two image third image will show . but when in click the image its showing the third image but in the left most side of the div.

but i have placed that image beside the two image.

i want to show that image beside that two image.

how to do this?

you can see my problem here
http://postimg.org/image/685puy931/

i am not using any float :left any where.(seen in firebug).

Please help

i searched tried with position absolute and inline its not working.

Thanks in advance

[EDIT]

```
showData += "<div style='margin:3px;display: inline-block;padding-right:20px;'>";
                        showData += "<a style='text-decoration: none' href=\"" + userProfileURL + "\" title='KLMS User Profile of " + fullName + " ' onmousedown=\"javascript:StoreClickedData(" + userId + ",'" + userInput + "','" + names[i] + "')\" title='" + tooltipTitle + "'> <img src='UserControls/ThumbNail/ThumbnailConverter.ashx?FilePath=" + imageURL + "&height=18&width=18' /> </a> ";
                        showData += "<a href=\"" + gpsUserProfile + "\" onmousedown=\"javascript:StoreClickedData(" + userId + ",'" + userInput + "','" + names[i] + "')\" title='" + tooltipTitle + "'>" + fullName + "</a>";
                        if (isPresent) {
                            showData += " <a href=\"" + emailId + "\" title='Mail To " + fullName + " ' onmousedown=\"javascript:StoreClickedAndLunchQuickFeedBack(" + userId + ",'" + userInput + "','" + names[i] + "','imgQuickfd" + imageId + "')\" class='smallIcon' style=\"background-image:url(Images/email.png);\" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
                            if (userDetails[userData.Skype_ID] != "null") {
                                showData += " <a href=\"" + skypeId + "\" title='Chat With " + fullName + "' onmousedown=\"javascript:StoreClickedAndLunchQuickFeedBack(" + userId + ",'" + userInput + "','" + names[i] + "','imgQuickfd" + imageId + "')\" class='smallIcon' style=\"background-image:url(" + skypeName + ");\" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
                            }
                            showData += "<i id='imgQuickfd" + imageId + "' style='display:none; cursor: pointer;position: absolute !important;' title='Quick Feedback To" + fullName + " ' onclick=\"javascript:StoreQuickFeedback('" + userLoginName + "','" + names[i] + "','imgQuickfd" + imageId + "')\" class=\"icon-thumbs-up glowed \"></i>";
                        }
                        showData += "</div>";
```

[/EDIT]

View Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="head"><title>
MFS Search Engine
</title><link href="CSS/CustomGoogleSearch.css" rel="stylesheet" /><meta charset="utf-8" /><link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post" action="CustomGoogleSearch.aspx?query=html5" id="form">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTQwMjc4OTQzN2RkRYBvMG1HTB0LNjZv1HE0hZ95t08=" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form'];
if (!theForm) {
theForm = document.form;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/klms    /WebResource.axd?d=YGVs8XyAWsEiLGuJ16c33zJSRK4YrDPiOWmkBO0Qq98589H5pLaw70AyFUVa3BleRpWNySSr    ltpIawWYHK6tn8jtCeo1&amp;t=634656060808104849" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/klms/WebResource.axd?d=rGkGTBKKUfifja4ZbpHfden_7XF4hf_qIjcSz4LqV8J7RmM4b5zUIgiT0uuMpRtVNMa-zLKNmfsh-e7Fd8RqdBTlqhM1&amp;t=634656060808104849" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION"     value="/wEWBgLFvND9DQKIiKT4AQK4gogyAvjE9ooCAoLplowDAt3Q4McN/MAodltIcChy5WGQ8XeHsiQlCY8=" />
</div>
        <noscript>
            <div class="jsEnable">
                <a href="https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&    answer=12654">How To Enable</a>
            <span>JavaScript is needed for this site (which is currently disabled in your browser). Please enable JavaScript.</span>
        </div>
    </noscript>
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnUserId" id="hdnUserId" value="595" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnUserName" id="hdnUserName" value="Annapurnap" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnRowCount" id="hdnRowCount" value="10" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnAPIServerName" id="hdnAPIServerName" value="http://203.129.204.51:8080/collective-intellegenc" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnSolrServerName" id="hdnSolrServerName" value="http://203.129.204.51:8080/solr" />


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
WebForm_AutoFocus('searchInput');//]]>
</script>
</form>
<form id="formResult">
    <div class="span18" id="divContent" style="width: 97%">
        <div style="width: 100%; margin-top: -10px" class="inline">
            <img id="imgGoogleCustomImage" class="googleCustomImage" style="float: right; margin-top: 0.25%" src="http://www.google.com/cse/images/google_custom_search_smwide.gif" />
            <a href="/FeedbackList.aspx" style="float: right; padding-right: 5%;">*Feedback List </a>
        </div>
        <div id="divSearch" class="searchDiv">
            <img src="Images/KLMS.png" id="imgLogo" />

            <div>
                <div id="divTextBox">
                    <input type="search" name="q" size="31" id="searchInput" class="span6" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
                <div id="divButton">
                    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" name="sa" class="btn btn-primary span2" value="Search" onclick="Search();" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="divResult" style="display: none; padding-top: 5%">
            <div class="divItem" style="float: left; margin-right: 1%; display: none;">
                <fieldset class="well" id="fieldsetItem">
                    <legend class="legend">Content that can help</legend>
                    <div id="searchResultItem">
                    </div>
                    <div id="divLinkPaging"></div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <aside style="float: left; width: 99%">
                <fieldset class="well" id="fieldsetPerson">
                    <legend class="legend">Persons who can help</legend>
                    <div id="searchResultPerson">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </aside>
        </div>
        <div id="divGoogleResult">
        </div>
        <script src="JS/Plugins/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--[if IE]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="JS/Plugins/paging.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Collective%20Intelligence/Collection.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Collective%20Intelligence/Solr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Collective%20Intelligence/ConnectServer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Collective%20Intelligence/UserConnection_UsabilityScore_UserSearch.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Collective%20Intelligence/FixedSet.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Collective%20Intelligence/VariableSet.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Collective%20Intelligence/ShowCollectiveIntelligenceData.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Collective%20Intelligence/StoreSearchQuery.js"></script>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: your container(possibly li) holding all those images, doesn't have enough width, to show all images inline. try increasing the width of the parent container

Comment: please post some code. also, what have you tried?

Comment: i am placing the image when the UI is showing. later i am just showing the image. how to fix the position of the image?? so that when i made that visibility true it will show at its right position.

Comment: hey, if you want to make it easy on us, goto the viewsource of your page and just copy and paste here, the exact markup of your that container responsible for this behavior

Comment: is it possible fix the position of an image irrespective the image's display is none or block.

Comment: to display icon-thumbs-up element are you changing display:none to block ??

Comment: yes i am doing that .Sorry for late reply

Comment: That could be your problem (`display: block` forces the element onto a new line). Try using `display: inline-block` instead.

Comment: already tried with that that is not working.

before i am writing like document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";  i replaced this code with jquery show function.

Now that problem is not occurring .

Comment: Thanks all for you suggestions and reply

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of things (though it's hard to tell without seeing any code... hint, hint) I would say that the container isn't wide enough for three images.

Try increasing the width by 10 pixels or so and see if that helps. You may need to decrease the padding/margins of the other elements to make room; again, I can't tell for sure without seeing code.

Answer (score 0):

In stand of

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
```

use jquery  [Show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method

that will not pull the tag to new line.